# Loop through UserForm

Tags: vba

i m trying to loop through project components and if the result is 3 (Userform) to loop through teach Userform and get it's control name and properties but i receive an error in the second for each.

any help will appreciate!!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Find_From_control()

    Dim Control As Control
    Dim Component As Object
    Dim LastRow As Long

     For Each Component In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        If Component.Type = 3 Then

            For Each Control In Form.Controls
                LastRow = wsControl.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                If TypeName(Control) = "TabStrip" Or TypeName(Control) = "ScrollBar" Or TypeName(Control) = "SpinButton" Or TypeName(Control) = "MultiPage" Or TypeName(Control) = "TextBox" Then
                    wsControl.Range("I" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Name
                    wsControl.Range("J" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Type
                    wsControl.Range("L" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Tag
                    wsControl.Range("M" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.TabIndex
                ElseIf TypeName(Control) = "Image" Then
                    wsControl.Range("I" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Name
                    wsControl.Range("J" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Type
                    wsControl.Range("L" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Tag
                ElseIf TypeName(Control) = "Frame" Or TypeName(Control) = "ToggleButton" Or TypeName(Control) = "OptionButton" Or TypeName(Control) = "CheckBox" Or TypeName(Control) = "Label" Or TypeName(Control) = "CommandButton" Then
                    wsControl.Range("I" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Name
                    wsControl.Range("J" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Type
                    wsControl.Range("K" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Caption
                    wsControl.Range("L" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Tag
                    wsControl.Range("M" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.TabIndex
                ElseIf TypeName(Control) = "ListBox" Or TypeName(Control) = "ComboBox" Then
                    wsControl.Range("I" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Name
                    wsControl.Range("J" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Type
                    wsControl.Range("L" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Tag
                    wsControl.Range("M" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.TabIndex
                    wsControl.Range("N" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.ColumnCount
                End If

            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: #Geshode the error is "variable not defined" i dont know how to get the name of the componet and loop through it for controls

Comment: Seems like you have to define a variable. Look at the line of the error message and make sure, that all variables are defined.

Comment: Your first loop uses `Component` as variable, but in your second loop you try to access `Form.Controls`.

Comment: #FunThomas i try to get the name from the first loop and create another loop to get the controls from the userform but i dont manage to.any ideas?

Comment: `wscontrol` is not declared. BTW I'd use other variable names than `Control` and `Component` as VBA may be confused meeting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Userform is the Component `Component.Designer`.

`Control.Type` is not a valid property, use `TypeName(Control)` instead.

```
Sub Find_From_control()

    Dim Control As Control
    Dim Component As Object
    Dim Form As UserForm
    Dim LastRow As Long

     For Each Component In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        If Component.Type = 3 Then
            Set Form = Component.Designer
            For Each Control In Form.Controls
                LastRow = wsControl.Range("I" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

                If TypeName(Control) = "TabStrip" Or TypeName(Control) = "ScrollBar" Or TypeName(Control) = "SpinButton" Or TypeName(Control) = "MultiPage" Or TypeName(Control) = "TextBox" Then
                    wsControl.Range("I" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Name
                    wsControl.Range("J" & LastRow + 1).Value = TypeName(Control)
                    wsControl.Range("L" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Tag
                    wsControl.Range("M" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.TabIndex
                ElseIf TypeName(Control) = "Image" Then
                    wsControl.Range("I" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Name
                    wsControl.Range("J" & LastRow + 1).Value = TypeName(Control)
                    wsControl.Range("L" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Tag
                ElseIf TypeName(Control) = "Frame" Or TypeName(Control) = "ToggleButton" Or TypeName(Control) = "OptionButton" Or TypeName(Control) = "CheckBox" Or TypeName(Control) = "Label" Or TypeName(Control) = "CommandButton" Then
                    wsControl.Range("I" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Name
                    wsControl.Range("J" & LastRow + 1).Value = TypeName(Control)
                    wsControl.Range("K" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Caption
                    wsControl.Range("L" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Tag
                    wsControl.Range("M" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.TabIndex
                ElseIf TypeName(Control) = "ListBox" Or TypeName(Control) = "ComboBox" Then
                    wsControl.Range("I" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Name
                    wsControl.Range("J" & LastRow + 1).Value = TypeName(Control)
                    wsControl.Range("L" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.Tag
                    wsControl.Range("M" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.TabIndex
                    wsControl.Range("N" & LastRow + 1).Value = Control.ColumnCount
                End If

            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```